# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' c# class getter

Tags: c#, class, get

```
class Fridge {
    public List<string> Food
    {
        get {
            string aliments = "";
            foreach (string aliment in Food)
            {
                aliments += $"{aliment} ";
            }
            return aliments;
        }
    }
```

I'm tryig to get a string of all the aliments inside a fridge and im getting the following error when i try to run the code Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type of the getter to `string` instead of `List<string>`.

```
public string Food  // <-- return type should be string, not List<string>
{
    get {
        string aliments = "";
        foreach (string aliment in Food)
        {
            aliments += $"{aliment} ";
        }
        return aliments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said your function would return a Collection of strings - `List<string>` to be precise.

Yet your return value is only a *single* string. C# as most .NET Langauges is very carefull with implicit conversions. And this is plain beyond what it will do.

You either want to create and fill a collection. Or use a concantenated string. Please decide.